# What are the possible values of the rank of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A \in M_5(R)$ is given by $x^5 + αx^4  + βx^3$
 where α and β are non-zero real numbers. What are the possible
values of the rank of $A$?

My attempt ;
  here  I got  three basis vectors: $(0,0,α,0,0) ,(0,0,0,β,0)$ and $(0,0,0,0,1)$,

so there are three  linearly independent vectors, so  as by rank nullity theorem

Rank of $A = 3$

is my answer is correct or not , i would be more thankful who will rectify my mistakes...

Comment: There is more than one possible rank.

Comment: When you say "i got three basis (vectors) (0,0,α,0,0) ,(0,0,0,β,0) and (0,0,0,0,1)", you surely mean basis vectors of the range of $A$, but how can you assert this ?

Comment: nullity A= 2 and  dimv = 5  so rank of A =3 @ jean marie

Answer (score 1):

$x^3(x^2+\alpha x+\beta)$.  You can find the dimension of the kernel. If  $\beta\neq 0$ you have two eigenvalues ( eventually one double) distinct of $0$, so the rank is greater than $2$ and inferior or equal to $4$ since one eigenvalue is zero.

if $\beta=0$ and $\alpha\neq 0$ the characteristic polynomial is $x^4(x+\alpha)$ you have an eigenvalue different of zero, so the rank is superior to $1$ and inferior or equal to $4$.

If $\alpha=\beta=0$, the characteristic polynomial is $x^5$ the rank is inferior to $4$.

Comment: thanks @ tsemo aristide,,,,,,im not gettingthe line   ( eventually one double) distinct of 0..

Comment: think about $(x-2)^2$ it has a double root.

Comment: that mean rank will be 2  ,,, how can u claim that rank is greater than 2@ tsemo aristide

Comment: Yes because $A^3=0$ does not imply that the rank of $A$ is zero.

Comment: ok thanks ..that mean rank will be 2, 3 ,,,,,but im not getting how  rank of A = 4 @ TSEMO ARISTIDE